# Retrieve names columns of all tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

Does there exist a system stored procedure that lists the names of all tables in a SQL Server 2000 database and per table the names of all columns in that table? I want to export this data to a file for documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if a system stored procedure exists, but I use this:

```
SELECT   SysObjects.[Name] as TableName,   
    SysColumns.[Name] as ColumnName,   
    SysTypes.[Name] As DataType,   
    SysColumns.[Length] As Length   
FROM   
    SysObjects INNER JOIN SysColumns   
ON SysObjects.[Id] = SysColumns.[Id]   
    INNER JOIN SysTypes  
ON SysTypes.[xtype] = SysColumns.[xtype]  
WHERE  SysObjects.[type] = 'U'  
ORDER BY  SysObjects.[Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server 2005+ you can do it using system views [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) and [sys.tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
SELECT t.name TableName, c.name ColumnName
FROM sys.tables t
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id=c.object_id
```

Comment: Thanks. But does not work for SQL Server version 2000 I think? Get an error message: "Invalid object name 'sys.tables'". I am using version 2000, sorry, should have mentioned this (updated my question).

Answer (score 0):

And you can also query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view.

It's also safer to use this view. [Microsoft says this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) about the view "Querying the system tables directly may not provide accurate information if system tables are changed in future releases. These views provide an internal, system table-independent view of the SQL Server meta data. Information schema views allow applications to work properly even though significant changes have been made to the system tables."